# Webscrape question Beautifulsoup all links on a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the links of the following website: https://www.electrive.com/category/automobile/

I want the links of all articles on page 1 listed in the output.

Thank you so much!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.electrive.com/category/automobile/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

overview = soup.find()

for c in overview.find('main', id='main').a['href']:
    print(c)
```

Desired output:

```
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/22/volkswagen-optimizing-id-3-production-in-the-uk/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/22/bmw-is-bringing-the-i4-to-china/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/22/vw-reconsiders-the-id-life-concept/
[... all links of the articles on page 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.select` for that, it does accept CSS selector and get all matching elements, in your case

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.electrive.com/category/automobile/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for a in soup.select("div.excerpt > a"):
    print(a["href"])
```

output (abrigded)

```
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/23/geely-plans-to-go-public-with-lotus-technology/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/23/geely-plans-to-go-public-with-lotus-technology/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/23/dacia-to-launch-a-smaller-electric-car-in-2024/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/23/dacia-to-launch-a-smaller-electric-car-in-2024/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/23/nissan-gives-the-leaf-a-fresh-facelift/
...
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/16/genesis-to-bring-the-gv60-to-europe-this-year/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/16/fisker-begins-accepting-reservations-for-the-pear/
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/16/fisker-begins-accepting-reservations-for-the-pear
```

Explanation: `div.excerpt > a` in CSS selector language means `<a>` which is child of `<div>` having `class` `excerpt`. I did devised such CSS selector after inspecting source of page you linked.

EDIT: If you need to avoid repeats and do not care about order you can do:

```
for href in set(a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.excerpt > a")):
    print(href)
```

EDIT2: If you must to preserve order do

```
seen = set()
for href in [a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.excerpt > a")]:
    if href in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(href)
    print(href)
```

Comment: love this way. the only problem is that I get the the same link twice. Any chance to remove the duplicates?

Comment: @webscrapeartist if you do not care about orders, and you have list named `links` then it should suffice to do `links = list(set(links))`

Comment: for article_list in soup.select("div.excerpt > a"): 
     #print(article_list["href"])
     links2 = article_list["href"]
     links2 = list(set(links2))
     print(links2)

Comment: doenst work. output: ['m', ':', 's', 'd', 'w', 'c', 'a', 'v', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'g', 't', 'h', '0', 'f', 'p', '/', 'i', 'e', '4', '-', '2', '.', 'y', 'r']
['m', ':', 's', 'd', 'w', 'c', 'a', 'v', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'g', 't', 'h', '0', 'f', 'p', '/', ...

Comment: @webscrapeartist do not apply this operation to each link, store all link in list named `links` then apply said operation

Comment: can you please tell me how to code that? Sorry I am new in python :) Thank you so much!!

Comment: is there also an option to sort them as on the website?